# Ruby - Prime Number calculator

Tags: ruby, primes

I need some feedback to figure out why I cant `puts` or `print` anything from my methods on the screen. This is a simple script I wrote to solve the problem of finding the 1001st prime number. Thanks

```
def primes
  # iterates through numbers until it has the 1001th prime number and returns it.
  # I chose to create the num_primes variable instead of counting the number of 
  # elements in in_prime_array every iteration
  # based upon a guess that it would be faster to check.

is_prime_array = []
  num_primes = 0
  i = 2
  loop do
    is_prime_array << i && num_primes += 1 if is_prime?(i) == true 
    i += 1
    break if num_primes == 1001
    end
  is_prime_array[1001]
end


def is_prime? (num)
# Checks to see if the individual number given is a prime number or not.
i = 2
  loop do
    if i == num
      return true
    elsif num % i == 0
      return false
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT

---

I took your advice and tried this pice of code:

```
def is_prime? (num)
  # Checks to see if the individual number given is a prime number or not.
  i = 2
  loop do
    if i == num
      return true
    elsif num % i == 0
      return false
    else
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

i = 0
count = 0
loop do
  count += 1 if is_prime?(x)
  puts "#{i}" if count == 1001
  break
end
```

It still returns nothing. Hummm

Comment: for better efficiency, in your `is_prime?` inside the `loop`, change it to `if i*i > num` `return true` `elsif ...`.

Comment: Being rigorous with indentation will make your life better. `i = 2` and `is_prime_array = []` should be 2 spaces in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 0
count = 0
loop do
  if is_prime(i)
    count += 1
  end

  if count == 10001
    puts "#{i}"
    break
  end
end
```

Simple method :)

Comment: Good suggestion. I implemented it but it still wont return anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's an off-by-one error. If you have 1001 elements in an array, the last element will be at index 1000.

Where you have

```
is_prime_array[1001]
```

Change it to

```
is_prime_array[1000]
```

And you can do this:

```
puts primes
 => 7927
```

You could also have

```
is_prime_array.last
```

instead of a specific index number.

Comment: Even after 30+ years of coding, I still make the same mistake on new projects. Which is why I saw this one.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to "puts"? The first thing I notice is that there is no call to `primes` in the file, so nothing will happen if you try to run this code by itself. Maybe that's why you don't see anything printed.

Here's an example of how to print a few variables inside your loop:

```
loop do
  ...
  puts "At iteration #{i}, we have prime=#{is_prime?(i)}"
```

If you don't know, enclosing a statement with `#{<statement goes here>}` inside a string is the same as appending the return value of `<statement goes here>` to the string at that position. This is the same as `"Str " + blah + " rest of str"` in a language like Java.

Comment: Sorry, I only wrote down the methods in the script and not where I tried to call them. Even when I write something like `puts primes` it still returns nothing. I dont even get an error.

Comment: I ran your code with my added puts statement and call to `primes()` on my local machine with Ruby 1.9.3 -- the puts does work. Make sure you're calling the function from somewhere (and if it's inside another function, make sure THAT function is being called). I added `primes()` at the bottom of the file to test this.